# Access Widget Attribute Through AttributeSet - Android

Tags: java, android, view, namespaces

This should be fairly simple task. I have a view with the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:panel="org.miscwidgets"

<org.miscwidgets.widget.Panel
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    panel:handle="@+id/panelHandle"
    panel:content="@+id/panelContent"
    panel:position="right">
```

I am attempting to access the position property in the constructor of the view, however it consistently returns null.

```
        String posVal = attrs.getAttributeValue("schemas.android.com/apk/gen/org.miscwidgets", "position");
```

How can I get the value? Is my namespace wrong?

I've seen references to Styleables but I've been unsuccessful in finding any that were not deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write in your xml

```
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/gen/org.miscwidgets"
```

Instead of

```
xmlns:panel="org.miscwidgets"
```

And get it by

```
attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/gen/org.miscwidgets", "position");
```